# Access to jsonb string value as array and find overlapping with another array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have an PostgeSQL table with column named 'params' which contains jsonb data:

```
{"type": "common_value", "value": "2453,10873" }
```

I would like to create SQL query which returns only rows with overlapping to another string set like ('2453', '4578', '9923').
I've tried the following query:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where params->>'value' in ('2453', '4578', '9923');
```

It works since those 'value' string contains only one integer (*'2453'*), when those 'value' looks like *'2453,4578'* there are no results.
I've read docs and questions here about json arrays and conversions and so on, but I was only able to find those things near SELECT, not next to WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

Unnest both arrays into 'tables' and join them to see if there is a match, i.e. overlap.

```sql
select * from TABLE_NAME where exists 
(
 select 
 from unnest(string_to_array(params->>'value', ',')) l 
 join unnest('{2453,4578,9923}'::text[]) r on l = r
);
```